# Is it "become elite" or "get elite" if I want to tell someone that I want to become one of the experienced at some topic?

Tags: word-choice

Is it "become elite" or "get elite" if I want to tell someone that I want to become one of the experienced at some topic? I am really confused at the moment.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You've actually answered your own question in your question.

Comment: So it is to become elite? That was my first intention, thank you, sometimes "become" and "get" is really confusing for me...

Comment: "Become" = change, "get" = acquire "I would like to **become** an elite programmer." vs "I would like to **get** elite programmer skills".

Comment: @user3169: that definition is not a particularly good one. IMHO this definition "the richest, most powerful, best-educated, or best-trained group in a society" is closer to the real meaning: it means "membership of the best <whatever> group", and that would be valid (if used correctly) for the OP's intent.

Comment: Just the other day I advised someone on ELL, "Don't use 'get *adjective*' unless you're really certain how to use it."  The rules for when you can use "get *adjective*" are very slippery and hard to pin down.  I would say you should learn a few stock phrases - *get angry, get hurt, get better, get well, get good* - and for everything else, use "become".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to become elite
>   I want to get elite.

I don't think that elite can be used in either context. To be used in this way, it would have to be an adjective- like for example.

> I want to become good

If you look at the adjective definition in the Cambridge Dictionary, you will see that it is only valid if followed by a noun. In neither of the above sentences is elite followed by a noun.

What you would actually say is something like:

> I want to become an elite  - *adjective*
>   I want to become a member of the elite - *noun*.

I don't think that you would consider **get** in either of these sentences.

Comment: What if you want to challenge someone to become one of the best players in an online game and text him: "Yo man, become elite!" Is that also just wrong? Or is it okay in common speech?

Comment: @JohnDoe  Very very wrong! That would be an adjectival use without a noun following it.

Comment: So it should be "[...], become an elite gamer" ?

Comment: @JohnDoe: exactly.